# Django- How to define django variable in template by javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, python, django

Is their any way to define django variable in template by javascript variable

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this in your script.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   var a = "{{yourVariable}}";
</script>
```

and store it as script variable

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have to do few thing before delcare any django variable in temple by using javascript:

**step 1: views.py**

```
def XYZfunc(request, abc):
    try:
        some code here...
        content = {'abc': abc}
        return render(request, 'ProjectName/xyz_html_page.html', content)

    except(ObjectDoesNotExist, KeyError, ValueError):
        content = {'abc': abc}
        return render(request, 'ProjectName/xyz_html_page.html', content)
```

**step 2: urls.py (optional)**

```
url(r'^ProjectName/xyz_htmlpage_name/(?P<abc>[A-Z]+)/$', views.XYZfunc, name="abc"),
```

> (please note: if you are sending value through html url from views.py
>   then use urls.py and if value is string then (?P[A-Z]+) )

**Step 3: xyz_html_page.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var u = "{{abc}}";
</script>
```

i hope it might help you.